# pause for loop until grep pattern from command meets condition (bash script)

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, grep

I want to send multiple jobs to a remote computer. Therefore I wrote a for loop which iterates over `i` jobs which consist of several subcommands. I need to pause the subsequent iteration until a certain subcommand is executed and the job actually runs on the remote computer.
So the idea is to check whether the string `"PEND"` appears in the output of a command on the remote computer. I want the for loop to continue when `"PEND"` changes to `"RUN"`. I don't know whether the if statement is the right thing to use here. A fixed waiting time by using `sleep` wouldn't do the trick as the status change from PEND to RUN is highly irregular.
Additional information: The subcommands comprise compilation of an executable.

Erroneous pseudocode:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    subcommands
    ...
    if [[ jobs | grep "PEND" == TRUE ]]; then sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: It sounds like you would benefit from [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: GNU parallel or you should use PID checking. Dont rely on the jobs command

Comment: As you iterate over the tasks in your loop, are you backgrounding these processes that are sent to the remote host? If not, why the need to pause? If so, we will need more substance to this question. At first glance though, I would swap out the `if` statement for a `while` loop. The `if` is only going to run 1x each outer `for` loop; you need a `while` or `until` in order to loop and continuously check a condition. Your condition is all kinds of wrong but I assume that isn't the condition you're actually using.